# How to setup an own Kibana client over aws ES service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I deployed an ES service 5.1 over AWS. The access policy is restricted to a unique IP. This public IP belongs to a EC2 instance (red hat).

At the EC2 instance, I installed kibana 5.1.2 using yum and I configured the kibana.yml as follows:

```
server.host: "ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
server.name: "my-kibana"
elasticsearch.url: "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com"
```

The rest config remains untouched.

With the EC2 instance I can do cURL requests over my ES with no problem (I had created an index, add some documents and search). But Kibana is giving me this error:

```
ui settings  Elasticsearch plugin is red
plugin:kibana@5.1.2  Ready
plugin:elasticsearch@5.1.2   Request Timeout after 3000ms
plugin:console@5.1.2     Ready
plugin:timelion@5.1.2    Ready
```

So I can't use my Kibana client. Can you tell what's missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `curl -XGET "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:9200"` command when it is executed from Kibana machine?

Comment: @avr no need to 9200 because ES is open on port 80. The result is: {
  "name" : "hNkhAMk",
  "cluster_name" : "xxxxxxxx:my-es-domain",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "5395e21",
    "build_date" : "2016-12-15T22:47:19.049Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.3.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: When you configure kibana with `elasticsearch.url: "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com"` it always look for es running on 9200 port by default. If you are running es on 80 port then explicitly mention that in configuration like this: `elasticsearch.url: "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80"`

Comment: @avr Wow! that helped a lot. It's working now. Thanks. You might want to copy your comment as answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Sure I'll add it as answer with reference links too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you configure kibana with

```
elasticsearch.url: "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com‌​"
```

it always look for es running on `9200` port by default.

If you are running es on `80` port then explicitly mention that in configuration 
like this:

`elasticsearch.url: "http://my-es-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com‌​:80"`

You can read more about this setting [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html#settings)

> **elasticsearch.url:**
>   Default: "http://localhost:9200" The URL of the Elasticsearch instance
>   to use for all your queries.

Comment: Awesome. Could be useful if this was specified in the documentation.

Comment: Also note that AWS runs it on port 443. ie `https://vpc-<stack_name>.<region>.es.amazonaws.com:443`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem locally, too. Elasticsearch and Kibana on local Debian 8 system. Although telnet/curl for localhost:9200 worked, I had to enable it in iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
```

Maybe this helps someone else, too.